# Django. Decorator issue.

Tags: python, django

I'm improving the standart poll app.

There I have some code that needs to be repeated in many views: code that counts number of various polls (active, inactive, popular) for posting the number in the links, such as:

> 1) View all active polls (number of polls).
>    2) View all closed polls
>   (number of polls).
>
> etc.

So matter of fact that I need repeat this code many times, I decided to make a decorator:

```
def count_number_of_various_polls(func):
    def count():
        # Count the number of active polls.
        all_active_polls = Poll.active.all()
        num_of_active_polls = len(all_active_polls)
        # Count the number of inactive polls.
        all_inactive_polls = Poll.inactive.all()
        num_of_inactive_polls = len(all_inactive_polls)
        # Count the number of popular polls per the last month.
        popular_polls = Poll.popular.filter(pub_date__gte=timezone.now() 
                                    - datetime.timedelta(days=days_in_curr_month))
        num_of_popular_polls = len(popular_polls)
        func()
    return count
```

Then I want to decorate my `index` view:

```
@count_number_of_various_polls
def index(request): 
    latest_poll_list = Poll.active.all()[:5]
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
        'num_of_popular_polls': num_of_popular_polls,
        'num_of_active_polls': num_of_active_polls,
        'num_of_inactive_polls': num_of_inactive_polls
        })
```

And when I try to open the polls index page on my dev server I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /polls/
count() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I have no idea what the 1 argument is.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument is the argument to the view, ie `request`. You need to accept that argument in your `count()` function, and pass it onto `func`:

```
def count_number_of_various_polls(func):
    def count(request):
        ...
        func(request)
    return count
```

However this isn't really a very good way of doing this, since you're still relying on the view itself to pass the elements into the template context. You should look into [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/) as better alternatives.